# Show latest posts in a plain HTML website custom widget

Tags: php, widgets, html

I have a plain HTML website with WP in a subfolder (/blog). I need to display latest posts from /blog into the plain HTML webpage.

Is there a PHP script or some kind of widget to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: There a lot of solutions to display recent posts from wordpress, you can call a recent posts widget, you can make a wordpress sidebar with recent posts widget and show this sidebar on your page, you can create wp_query or use get_posts functions, so it's your decision, but first, try to do 2 steps from my answer before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could consider using [WP REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) to get the [posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/) with a [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) in javascript instead of trying to get php work on .html file(s).

From the REST handbook,

> The WordPress REST API provides an interface for applications to
> interact with your WordPress site by sending and receiving data as
> JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) objects.

And

> It provides data access to the content of your site, and implements
> the same authentication restrictions — content that is public on your
> site is generally publicly accessible via the REST API, while private
> content, password-protected content, internal users, custom post
> types, and metadata is only available with authentication or if you
> specifically set it to be so.

Answer (score 1):

**1) Run php code in html files**

You can't run PHP in .html files because the server does not recognize that as a valid PHP extension unless you tell it to. To do this you need to create a .htaccess file in your root web directory and add this line to it:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
```

This will tell Apache to process files with a .htm or .html file extension as PHP files. 
([related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312316/how-do-i-add-php-code-file-to-html-html-files))

**2) Use Wordpress functionality outside of wordpress folder**

If you able to use php in your html files, you need to include wordpress `wp-load.php` file to load wordpress functionality. I'm not familiar with your folders' structure, so you will need to modify a path to this file by yourself.

```
require_once( '../blog/wp-load.php' );
```

Comment: Bear in mind that this will make the server process each HTML file as PHP before sending it to the user which will slow down the site. You would be better looking at the json API and getting the post content using js.

Comment: Totally agree))